# Send Private Messages to Facebook Page Followers PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-send-api

I have been working with Facebook PHP SDK a couple of days ago. And I have read in the Facebook Docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/) that it is possible to send a private messages to users if you have their phone number but this does not seem to work.

Here is my Code:

```
     $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
      // . . .
      ]);
    $post = [
  'access_token' => $_SESSION['page_access_token'],
  'message'      =>  
  [
    'text' => 'Hello, wadup?!!!'
  ],
  'recipient' => [
    'id' => '+1(0)0000000000'
  ]
];

$response = $fb->post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?', $post, $_SESSION['page_access_token']);
print_r($response);
```

The output:

```
Facebook\FacebookResponse Object ( [httpStatusCode:protected] => 200 [headers:protected] => Array ( [x-page-usage] => {"call_count":1,"total_cputime":1,"total_time":1} [Strict-Transport-Security] => max-age=15552000; preload [x-fb-trace-id] => CQO0hjDHbf0 [x-fb-rev] => 3535263 [Expires] => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8 [facebook-api-version] => v2.11 [Cache-Control] => private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate [Pragma] => no-cache [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => * [Vary] => Accept-Encoding [X-FB-Debug] => WYq6KntFxQ/uTEK8B4tsvF+UfAXzsTtpm4yJcVxkrXkxTPo04yx/ITqLTe8Ho7k+tLhzC87eNojGjjgKXaGnIg== [Date] => Mon, 18 Dec 2017 09:43:11 GMT [Connection] => keep-alive [Content-Length] => 82 ) [body:protected] => {"id":"1157989877575188","url":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.6\/me\/messages"} [decodedBody:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1157989877575188 [url] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages ) [request:protected] => Facebook\FacebookRequest Object ( [app:protected] => Facebook\FacebookApp Object ( [id:protected] => 1709050269133889 [secret:protected] => 1ceb6a6e1e4419f2799e699ebae2808e ) [accessToken:protected] => EAAYSX0Yx7EEBAH11ZAg7RWx60038nfYK1V1gOzqnu2NG0riV9DWiMRIJ9tZBfQwxqo92OaXx6uzhDZBn3xji8LXBP3mChJpbrCKpRLniUob9YlE1wZA3cnMSFIjA8eBjEaAUMJRfYvOBGfP7hIqMzNDU7fOPQOyXLFlPZAbdMZAQZDZD [method:protected] => POST [endpoint:protected] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages [headers:protected] => Array ( [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded ) [params:protected] => Array ( [message] => Array ( [text] => Hello, wadup?!!! ) [recipient] => Array ( [id] => 100002192125690 ) ) [files:protected] => Array ( ) [eTag:protected] => [graphVersion:protected] => v2.3 ) [thrownException:protected] => )
```

I have also tried using the recipients Facebook ID according to the documentation, but it doesn't work still.

Comment: are you trying to REPLY to a message? because that would be important, you can only reply.

Comment: No, trying to send for the first. But Facebook states in their documentation that this could be possible provided that you have the recipient's phone number

Comment: the biggest question is: how did you even GET the phone number?

Comment: also, according to the docs, the "id" is not the phone number, there is a specific phone number field. the id is the one you get when users interact with your messenger bot.

Comment: @Aldan My client who has this job legally collects Names, emails and Phone numbers from his customers, now he wants to reach them through Facebook

Comment: @luschn thanks so much. But I have also tried the `phone_number` field in the `recipient` object but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I know is an old question, but i arrived here and this could helps other in their researches.

> Facebook does not allow to a bot to write to an user if the user did
>   not interact with the bot on the Messanger app.

You can find an exaustive list of the possible interactions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/introduction/entry-points)